# Cannot Filter Context Root Servlet Requests

Tags: servlets, glassfish, glassfish-3, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0

I have a `@WebServlet("")` and a `@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"", "/", "/*"}, asyncSupported = true)`

But the filter is not being invoked for the servlet :-(

I am using `@WebServlet("")` instead of `@WebServlet("/")` based on instructions in: http://www.java.net/node/700651?force=613

I am using the Glassfish version bundled in the latest Java EE 6 SDK bundled with Java SE 7.  (I switched from using the latest GA of Jetty because Jetty incorrectly implements `@WebServlet("")`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Glassfish and according to a kind member on the Glassfish forum: http://www.java.net/node/700651#comment-821081 the workaround is to filter by servlet name in addition to the URL patterns. This also requires giving a name to the servlet. So the annotations would be: `@WebServlet(name = "foo", urlPatterns = "")` and `@WebFilter(servletNames = "foo", urlPatterns = {"", "/*"})` and once the bug is fixed you can remove the name of the servlet and  the explicit reference to it in the filter.

Comment: Those developers on Glassfish got on it really promptly and fixed it super-quickly!! http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18132  (boo Jetty!)